# Getting error missing required architecture arm64 and missing required architecture X86_64 for Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

If my library is not compiled for arm64 and X86_64 then how can I solve this issue.

I have tried to exclude this Architecture but still no luck.
I am getting this error only for the simulator for Xcode 12, on device it working fine.
my project is for iPhone and Apple watch.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Apparently updating to Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262) and updating the command line tools fixed it for me.